# react & bootstrap with laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.6, bootstrap 3.3.7 and recently added some react components with react native.

The thing is I have a dropdown that is included with bootstrap and everything is working just fine.

```html
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">{{__('nav.categorias')}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="/a/route">a name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="/c/route">c name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="/b/route">b name</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
```

When i click in the dropdown the options are getting diplayed correctly.

But when I add (as laravel react said)

`<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>`

The dropdown is not working any more.

I saw in the source-page that the bootstrap and jquery files are beeing added and the source code is just fine.

Should I migrate my bootstrap native to react bootstrap dropdown native?

Any ideas?

Comment: You said you're using Laravel but then said you added some react native.  This doesn't make sense.  Laravle and React Native don't go hand in hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using both `app.js` and `bootstrap.js`, `jquery.js`? If so, try removing `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js`. Otherwise you're running the same code twice which may cause problems.

Comment: Oh! That works but now I'm loosing another features from bootstrap LOL. At least I have a partial solution.

Comment: What features are you losing? Bootstrap in app.js should be the same as normal Bootstrap.

Comment: The nav is not holding the background color on scrolling down.

Comment: do you have any other idea why is this happening?

Comment: I wouldn't know, maybe a version diffrence?

Comment: I have just solved it. I added all the .js to the app.js file